# How to parse individual pixels from each line into numbers

Tags: python, parsing, text-files

I have a txt file that contains information as such:

```
RGB
768
768
08 87 68
118 101 83
110 92 72
114 96 76
115 97 77
```

The  first two numbers are the width and height of the original txt file and it is very large. I need to read the information and then convert it into a grayscale image using three different formulas. I have the first formula in my code already:

```
gray = (red + green + blue) / 3
```

But now I'm not sure how to actually parse each pixel, reading each line and each number in each line. I'm not familiar with python yet, so I understand basic functions but not necessarily the syntax and all yet.

I am writing it into a new txt file in the same format, just converted to grayscale, so :

```
RGB
768
768
54 54 54
100 100 100
91 91 91
95 95 95
96 96 96
```

```
   with open('1.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    content_list = input_file.readlines()
    width = 768
    height = int(len(content_list) / width)

    listRGBs = [] 

    with open('fsanche4_1.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        i = 0
        j = 0

        print(f"{int(height)}")
        out_file.write(f"RGB\n")
        out_file.write(f"{height}\n")
        out_file.write(f"{width}\n")    
       
        for i in range(0, height, 1):
            #row = listRBGs[i]
            for row in listRGBS:

              for j in range(0, width, 1):
                blue = row[j]
                red = row[j + 1]
                green = row[j + 2]

                gray = (red + green + blue) / 3
                out_file.writelines(f"{gray} {gray} {gray}\n")
```

The new code I wrote compiles and creates a new file but nothing appears in my new text file, only the first three lines and the rest is empty

```
RGB
768
768
```

Here's the new code I have :

```
with open('1.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    line = input_file.readlines()
    width = 768
    height = 768

    with open('fsanche4_1.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        i = 0
        j = 0
        print(f"{int(height)}")
        out_file.write(f"RGB\n")
        out_file.write(f"{height}\n")
        out_file.write(f"{width}\n")

        for line in input_file:
          blue, red, green = line.split()
          gray = (int(red) + int(green) + int(blue)) / 3
          out_file.write(f"{gray} {gray} {gray}\n")
        line = input_file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I have this right, but if you want some quick and simple (not the most elegant solution):

```py
with open('input.txt') as f, open('output', 'w') as o:

    line = f.readline()

    while line:
        try:
            blue, red, green = line.split()
        except ValueError as e:
            o.write(line)
            line = f.readline()
            continue
        grey = (int(blue) + int(red) + int(green)) / 3
        o.write(f'{int(grey)}\n')
        line = f.readline()
```

Its handling the:

```py
RGB
768
768
```

that makes it kinda messy. I just catch the ValueError that gets raised when you try to unpack 1 value into 3.

Also, just thinking out loud, it seems like your trying to store a 2d array of pixel RGB references in just a list which could get confusing if anyone else used your code, i.e. does it do each column or each row sequentially? Maybe this is why your using the double for loop, to assign x and y, but you're not storing that reference as your only writing a RBG -> Gray conversion.

In any case, the code block will switch the first file you have to the second.  Hope it helps.

Comment: So the first three lines are just formatting, I don't have to include them in any for loop or functions, I just have to print them out. But for my code, this is what I have but nothing is printing out to my output file, only the 'RGB
768
768'

Comment: I added the new code I used to my original question

Comment: Ok yeah thats no problem, I figured it would be a tossup if they stay or not.  My code will still work if you feed it an input file with each line consisting of 3 integers, regardless if the first 3 lines are RGB, 768, 768 or not. Give it a shot and if you still have questions hit me up.